# Convert string to date and compare to file creation time

Tags: bash, date

I am trying to compare a string converted to date and a file creation time in bash.

```
#!/bin/bash

test='2020-05-13 08:00'
testConverted=$(date -d "$test" +'%Y %m %d %H:%M')
[ "~/fileToCompare" -nt "$testConverted" ] && echo "yes"
```

This always returns false no matter what date I put for test. Is the conversion of the date wrong? Is this possible to do?

Comment: The tilde `~` does not expand in quotes, try `$HOME` instead.

Comment: Thanks, it is always returning "true" now no matter what date I enter.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is to convert the date string into Unix Epoch time (seconds since Jan 1, 1970) with the `date` command and then similarly get the Epoch time modification date of the test file using the `stat` command and compare using arithmetic evaluation

```
#!bin/bash

testDate='2020-05-13 08:00'
testFile="$HOME/fileToCompare"

if (( $(date -d "$test" +%s) > $(stat "$testFile" -c %Z) )); then
  echo "testDate ($testDate) is newer than $testFile"
fi
```